# VIsual Studio Code - Live Sass Compiler Not Generating .css File in Separate css Folder

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set the save location of my css file to its own css folder in the Live Sass Compile Config (Live Sass Compile > Settings:Formats)

I have tried setting the savePath to "/css" - After this - I tried saving my main.scss file, which is supposed to generate a css folder with a main.css file in it. However, it is just generating a main.css file in the same folder as my main.scss (which is in a scss folder).

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling VSC but my previous settings were saved.

{
        "format": "expanded",
        "extensionName": ".css",
        "savePath": "/css",
        "window.zoomLevel": 0,
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.wordWrap": "off"
}

The code above is all that shows in my .json file. The top 3 lines are greyed/blacked out (format to save path).

This display in my .json file is way different than what I'm finding in tutorials on this.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest you to avoid using that for sass.
Use node-sass instead. It's super easy to setup and run!
Just install it from command line:
`npm i node-sass -g`
And run it in the background:
`node-sass [entry path-to-file] [output-path-to-file] -w`
The `-w` watches for changes in your .sass or .scss file and compiles straight away!

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out! However, I am still trying to figure out my question. Take care :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `settings.json` rename the path form `"\css"` to `"\\css"`

Like this:

```
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "\\css"
        }
```

Don't worry it's how VS Code understands file paths. Not your fault:)

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the main css file for every change in your child scss files (ctrl+s)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32223316)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you renamed your sass main file style.scss.

If your sass main file have underscore before name like _style.scss, your live sass compiler will not generate .css file.

> So rename your main sass file from _style.scss to style.scss.